# How to add elements to a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

i'm actually learning Python and i want to make a matrix (4x5) and replace with coordinates.
Here is the code of the matrix:

```
grid = [["+" for i in range(4)] for j in range(5)]

for k in grid:
    print(k)
   0    1    2    3
0['+', '+', '+', '+']
1['+', '+', '+', '+']
2['+', '+', '+', '+']
3['+', '+', '+', '+']
4['+', '+', '+', '+']
```

For example: I want to put "-" in (0,1) and (1,1). It should look like this:

```
   0    1    2    3
0['+', '+', '+', '+']
1['-', '-', '+', '+']
2['+', '+', '+', '+']
3['+', '+', '+', '+']
4['+', '+', '+', '+']
```

I really try but i don't have any idea how to add an element and save it in the matrix :/

Thanks, i hope they can understand my question.

Comment: Could you solve the problem if it were just a list, like say you had `['+', '+', '+', '+']` and you wanted to change it to `['+', '-', '+', '+']`?

Comment: To get programs correct, you must be precise in your thinking; it helps to be precise in your language. It's clear, for example, that you don't want to "add" elements to the matrix, because the matrix should be the same size before and after. You instead want to *replace* them.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is just a list of lists. You can update a coordinate using the list indexes.

Try this code:

```
grid = [["+" for i in range(4)] for j in range(5)]

for k in grid:
    print(k)

print()

grid[1][0] = '-'
grid[1][1] = '-'

for k in grid:
    print(k)
```

Output

```
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']

['+', '+', '+', '+']
['-', '-', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '+']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def insert(grid,
           what  = None,
           coord = None):
    
    r,c = coord
    grid[r][c] = what
    

grid = [["+" for i in range(4)] for j in range(5)]
insert(grid, what = "-", coord = (1,1))

for k in grid:
    print(k)
```